# Sort, threshold and display table data based on certain column

Tags: sorting, sed, awk, grep

I have a huge data file in table format to be analysed. Mainly two columns are of my interest where one containing names in alphanumeric letters (column #1) and other one containing percentage numbers (column #3).

My requirement is to reverse sort data based on values of column #3, apply some threshold (>10.0) and only display desired rows qualifying this criteria with column #1 and column #3 in sorted order.

Generally I write a small `perl` script to achieve such requirement. But here I am looking for a chain of linux commands (one liner) to solve it quickly and in efficient way.

**Sample Input**

```
abc12   24.5     90.0    5  
xyz23   454.23   23.5    2
aa34cd  1.345    12.34   6
uvxy    4.25     54.7    1
pqr3t   235.3    6.05    4
abcd    1.234    4.56    3
```

**Desired Output**

```
abc12   90.0
uvxy    54.7
xyz23   23.5
aa34cd  12.34
```

It would be appreciable if you could help me solve this problem.

**What I have tried?**

I could reverse sort on column #3 using following command. Not sure what's next!

```
awk '{print $3}' test.txt | sort -rn
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only print the first and third field if the third is greater than 10 then do a numeric reverse order sort on the second field:

```
$ awk '$3>10{print $1,$3}' file | sort -nrk 2
abc12    90.0
uvxy     54.7
xyz23    23.5
aa34cd   12.34
```